# Creating an SMTP Server c#

Tags: c#, smtp

I am currently working on an email server that when it receives an email it will it add it to a queue, and if it fails to be sent it can then get retried and also based on what it receives sends an auto reply message.

What I am looking at being able to do, is the email server can also be an smtp server, so the user could configure, let's say php or another email client use my email server smtp and it can receive the message and then process it.

Is this something that is possible and how can I get it started, haven't found that much help on Google, it needs to work with mono (linux) and normal .net (Windows).

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: A "email server that receives email (via SMTP)" **is** an SMTP server.  My suggestion is to refer to the source code of famous SMTP servers like postfix, etc. Don't ask people to give you a completed code like that

Comment: I'm not asking for complete code, don't know where you even got that impression from, and at the moment it currently doesn't receive email via smtp, instead it just receives an XML message which I just used for testing purposes to get the main part of the program working.

Comment: That's a lot of description to simply say, "I'm writing a standard email server."  Glazing over the fact that there are _tons_ of perfectly good email servers you could use... What is your question?

Comment: Please consider starting with something that is not immediately dangerous for everyone else - SMTP server working as open relay is not something most people/providers what to see on they network. Start with creating basic HTTP server which have similar communication code, but much smaller potential impact on other people. Or implement Telnet server.

Comment: Indeed, this looks to be a case of reinventing the wheel. Just install any standard SMTP server that is network accessible by your applications. Then in C# send messages to it with 

    `var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress();
    var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mysite.com");
    client.Send(message);`

And then move on to more important things

Comment: @arserbin3 It seems to me that there are many reasons why that might not be enough - you might want to reject mails under certain conditions, for example, and it could be way easier to just roll your own smtp server than to make a third-party one do what you want. It also simplifies deployment to have less components. This question isn't nearly as bad or illegitimate as people here make it out to be.

Comment: WHY is this Closed? It is easy to see whats being asked! I dont get the logic!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here are examples of SMTP server implementation in C#:
[Create a simple SMTP server in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/286952/create-a-simple-smtp-server-in-csharp)
[SMTP and POP3 Mail Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3991/SMTP-and-POP3-Mail-Server)

Comment: Thank you for the links!  This is a lot more useful than comments asking "why do you need this?" or "oh is that all?" - which are highly unconstructive and discourage people from asking questions in the future.

Comment: Mit license server that I am building: https://github.com/DigitalRuby/MailDemon