# Read Outlook emails in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outlook, exchange-server

I need some advice on how to solve a problem. I have an application that sends out emails to users. Note, I am using `Microsoft Exchange` as `email` server. I would like to have a feature where the user can reply to the email sent by the application and the application be able to read the reply and perform certain actions.

For example, the application will send out an email requesting approval for an item. I would like the user to reply the email and say whether or not the item has been approved or rejected. It's a very simple scenario but it captures what I want to do. How can I read emails sent to a particular address in `c#`?

Comment: Just have a look at [**This**](https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=7)

Answer (score 1):

Reading, parsing and answering emails in code is often very hard piece of machinery. If you are open to suggestions though one of the possible solutions could be a couple of Approve/Reject links in the body of the email which are linking back to your web site and triggering corresponding actions in your approval workflow. Hope it helps!

Comment: Based on my research, I am finding out that is will be a difficult task. I have the links but because the server is on a private network, it won't work when the user is outside the network or on the Internet. I don't believe the company wants to put their application on the Internet. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Properly configured and authenticated reverse proxy might do the job for you if the issue is only about the security of the internal perimeter. If you are really locked to receiving and parsing here is a good example of how it can be done mailin.io

Comment: Here is the answer with the examples of how it can be done in C# http://stackoverflow.com/a/11457840/920557

Answer (score 0):

You can use EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you are dealing with Office 365 you may also consider using [Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

If you use Outlook for sending emails consider using the [VotingOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866063(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class which allows to set a string specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message. This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple voting options. So, in a response you can use the [VotingResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868303.aspx) property which returns a string specifying the voting response for the mail message. This property is usually set to one of the delimited values returned by the VotingOptions property on a reply to the original message.